# Modulo no funciona como debería

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, lógica, metodología

Tengo el modulo `Parametros.py` con tres métodos que reciben como argumento un valor (`valorAñadido...`).

El primero es booleano y debería regresar `True` hasta que reciba `False` como argumento, sin poder volver a cambiar.

El segundo y el tercero son numéricos, la primera vez deberían hacer una suma entre el valor inicial (que es 0) y un valor añadido. Después de eso deberían regresar la suma entre el valor añadido y el valor anterior.

El código va algo así:

```
class Valores():
    def __init__(self):
        self.valorInicialParametroUno= True
        
        self.valorInicialParametroDos= 0
        self.valorInicialParametroTres= 0
    
        self.valorFinalParametroDos= 0
        self.valorFinalParametroTres= 0
  
    
class Evaluar(Valores):
    def p1(self, valorAñadidoParametroUno):
        if self.valorInicialParametroUno != valorAñadidoParametroUno:
            self.valorAñadidoParametroUno = valorAñadidoParametroUno
        else:
            self.valorAñadidoParametroUno = self.valorInicialParametroUno
        print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Uno: {self.valorAñadidoParametroUno}")
        return self.valorAñadidoParametroUno

    def p2(self, valorAñadidoParametroDos):
        self.valorAñadidoParametroDos = valorAñadidoParametroDos
        if self.valorInicialParametroDos == 0:
            self.valorFinalParametroDos = self.valorInicialParametroDos + self.valorAñadidoParametroDos
            self.valorInicialParametroDos=+ 1
            print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Dos: {self.valorAñadidoParametroDos}")
            return self.valorAñadidoParametroDos
        else:
            self.valorFinalParametroDos = self.valorFinalParametroDos + self.valorAñadidoParametroDos
            print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Dos: {self.valorAñadidoParametroDos}")
            return self.valorAñadidoParametroDos

    def p3(self, valorAñadidoParametroTres):
        self.valorAñadidoParametroTres = valorAñadidoParametroTres
        if self.valorInicialParametroTres == 0:
            self.valorFinalParametroTres = self.valorInicialParametroTres + self.valorAñadidoParametroTres
            self.valorInicialParametroTres=+ 1
            print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Tres: {self.valorAñadidoParametroTres}")
            return self.valorAñadidoParametroTres
        else:
            self.valorFinalParametroTres = self.valorFinalParametroTres + self.valorAñadidoParametroTres
            print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Tres: {self.valorAñadidoParametroTres}")
            return self.valorAñadidoParametroTres
```

Lo que regresa no es el resultado de la suma, si no los valores que se pasan como argumento.

Estuve haciendo muchísimas pruebas de diversas formas que me es difícil describir por aquí. La única que me funciono (nuevamente gracias Benito-B) es crear en la clase un constructor con los valores iniciales en 0, solo así lograba hacerse la suma... pero solo funciona cuando es un solo método.

Pondría un ejemplo del código funcional pero entre estar modificándolo para buscar otra solución termine perdiéndolo ;( y el que tengo ahora es el que mantiene el problema...

No tengo idea de lo que esta mal y por que si funciona en el ejemplo que ya no tengo pero en el código original no.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que evitar las tildes en tu código, pueden dar error, por lo que las he sustituido por una n clásica (tenlo en cuenta si prefieres volver a ponerlas).
El constructor debería estar en la clase de tus parámetros, es decir en la clase *Evaluar()*, además he añadido los tres parámetros de *valorAñadido* que no estaban presentes en el constructor para inicializarlos.
En cuanto al booleano, te sobra la parte del *else* en el condicional, de esta manera, se inicializa a *True*, y en cuanto cambia a *False*, se queda en *False* para el resto del programa.
Y en cuanto a los valores numéricos, retornabas el valor añadido, y no el valor final, he sustituido *valorAnadido...* por *valorFinal...* en los retornos y en los *print*.
Cos esos cambios llega a lo que propones en tu descripción del código. Se queda así:

```
class Evaluar():   

# Constructor de la clase Evaluar
def __init__(self):
    self.valorInicialParametroUno= True
    self.valorInicialParametroDos= 0
    self.valorInicialParametroTres= 0
    self.valorFinalParametroDos = 0
    self.valorFinalParametroTres = 0
    self.valorAnadidoParametroUno = 0
    self.valorAnadidoParametroDos = 0
    self.valorAnadidoParametroTres = 0

# Funcion p1
def p1(self,valorAnadidoParametroUno):
    if self.valorInicialParametroUno != valorAnadidoParametroUno:
        self.valorAnadidoParametroUno = valorAnadidoParametroUno
    print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Uno: {self.valorAnadidoParametroUno}")
    return self.valorAnadidoParametroUno

# Funcion p2
def p2(self, valorAnadidoParametroDos):
    self.valorAnadidoParametroDos = valorAnadidoParametroDos
    if self.valorInicialParametroDos == 0:
        self.valorFinalParametroDos = self.valorInicialParametroDos + self.valorAnadidoParametroDos
        self.valorInicialParametroDos=+ 1
        print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Dos: {self.valorFinalParametroDos}")
        return self.valorFinalParametroDos
    else:
        self.valorFinalParametroDos += self.valorAnadidoParametroDos
        print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Dos: {self.valorFinalParametroDos}")
        return self.valorFinalParametroDos
# Funcion p3
def p3(self, valorAnadidoParametroTres):
    self.valorAnadidoParametroTres = valorAnadidoParametroTres
    if self.valorInicialParametroTres == 0:
        self.valorFinalParametroTres = self.valorInicialParametroTres + self.valorAnadidoParametroTres
        self.valorInicialParametroTres=+ 1
        print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Tres: {self.valorFinalParametroTres}")
        return self.valorFinalParametroTres
    else:
        self.valorFinalParametroTres += self.valorAnadidoParametroTres
        print(f"Soy el valor del Parametro Tres: {self.valorFinalParametroTres}")
        return self.valorFinalParametroTres
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Cumple perfectamente su cometido y gracias por las recomendaciones, había olvidado totalmente lo de los símbolos romanizados (creo que esta bien empleada esa palabra).